# how to set run nginx config for running two frontend apps and a backend server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I was trying to setup two frontend react applications sharing a server written in nodejs. I tried setting up one frontend application it worked correctly but gets an error `host not found in upstream "server" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` when i add the other one.

here is my docker-compose

```
version: "3"
services:
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:latest"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres_password
  nginx:
    depends_on:
      - api
      - client
      - client2
    restart: always
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "3050:80"
  api:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: "./server"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:/app
    environment:
      - PGUSER=postgres
      - PGHOST=postgres
      - PGDATABASE=postgres
      - PGPASSWORD=postgres_password
      - PGPORT=5432
  client:
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:/app
  client2:
    stdin_open: true
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
      context: ./client2
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client2:/app
```

nginx default.conf

```
upstream client {
    server client:3000;
}

upstream client2 {
    server client:3000;
}

upstream api {
    server api:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
    }

    location /login {
        proxy_pass http://client2;
    }

    location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }
}
```

apart from the above my two frontend react applications (client, client2) also contains an nginx directory with default.conf
client/nginx/default.conf

```
server{
    listen 3000;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

client2/nginx/default.conf

one of my client Dockerfile.dev

```
FROM node:14.14.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

one of my client Dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.14.0-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm i
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx
EXPOSE 3000
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Comment: You want one of your frontend app functional as a subdomain or you want just a route for the second f.app?

Comment: would prefer it to be a subdomain but if not possible i can settle with a route

Comment: with the _linuxserver/swag_ image you can easily create subdomains. (it will even create you SSL certificates and so on) For the subdomain you will have a seperate _xy.subdomain.conf_ file where you have to put your _server_ block.. for more info: (https://docs.linuxserver.io/general/swag#subdomain-proxy-conf)

Comment: I read the documentation @Tivi that you had attached after seeing that i decided to go with for the routes. can you provide the solution for that as well?

Comment: Check out my https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72019400/subdomain-setup-for-second-frontend-app-in-my-nginx-config question. I think our problem is very close - meanwhile I found the solution to mine. _(I think you can implement it to yours)_ Go to /nginx/config/nginx/proxy-confs/admin.subdomain.conf and here the server_name should be yoursubdomain.example.com. $upstream_app is the name of your client2 container and the $upstream_port is the port.. If you can't proceed let me know and I will paste total solution as soon as I have some time.

Comment: In your main nginx container in docker-compose add this to volumes: - ./nginx/admin.conf:/config/nginx/proxy-confs/admin.subdomain.conf and all others I added as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use *linuxserver/swag* images for subdomains, and etc.. your files would be:

docker-compose.yaml:

```
  nginx:
    image: linuxserver/swag
    ports:
       - 80:80
       - 443:443
    volumes:
       - ./nginx/config:/config
       - ./nginx/default.conf:/config/nginx/site-confs/default
       - ./nginx/ssl.conf:/config/nginx/ssl.conf
    container_name: nginx
    networks:
      main:
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment: 
       - PUID=1000
       - PGID=1000
       - TZ=Europe/Berlin
       - URL=example.eu
       - SUBDOMAINS=www,something #put your domain seperated by ','
       - VALIDATION=http
       - STAGING= false #optional 
       - EMAIL=asd@abc.com
    depends_on:
       - client1
       - client2
       - api
```

*something.subdomain.conf* file for your subdomain in */nginx/config/nginx/proxy-confs*:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    server_name client2.*; #client2 (your docker container for your second frontend) or your subdomain...

    include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

    client_max_body_size 0;


    location / {

     include /config/nginx/proxy.conf;
     include /config/nginx/resolver.conf;
     set $upstream_app client2;
     set $upstream_port 3001;
     set $upstream_proto https;
     proxy_pass $upstream_proto://$upstream_app:$upstream_port;

 }
}
```

NGINX *default.conf* file:

```
upstream api {
    server api:5001;
}

upstream client {
    server client1:3000;
}



server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name _;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  
}

# main server block
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

  server_name _;

  # enable subfolder method reverse proxy confs
  include /config/nginx/proxy-confs/*.subfolder.conf;

  # all ssl related config moved to ssl.conf
  include /config/nginx/ssl.conf;

  client_max_body_size 0;
   
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client1;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }


     location /api {
        proxy_pass http://api;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }
}
# enable subdomain method reverse proxy confs
include /config/nginx/proxy-confs/*.subdomain.conf;
```

Please read these for more info:

- https://docs.linuxserver.io/general/swag#subdomain-proxy-conf
- https://github.com/linuxserver/reverse-proxy-confs
- ( https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-swag )
- https://medium.com/@mahmed_mushtaq/mern-application-deployment-on-digital-ocean-with-docker-part-2-840f5d429061
- https://medium.com/@mahmed_mushtaq/deploying-a-mern-application-on-digital-ocean-with-docker-part-1-cc3932e0d620

Answer (score 0):

You need to point your set your upstream clients in your nginx config to be the names of the services in your docker-compose.  Specifically here, you need to change under client2

```
upstream client {
    server client:3000;
}

upstream client2 {
    server client2:3000;
}

upstream api {
    server api:5000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client;
    }

    location /login {
        proxy_pass http://client2;
    }

    location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://client;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
    }

    location /api {
        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }
}
```

Comment: tried making this change but it gives out the same error